# Removing empty strings with a space in it (" ") in a array column of a Dataframe Series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list-comprehension

Example:

```
Column 1

[1, 3, " "]

[2, " ", 3]

etc.
```

Is there a quick list compehension where I can keep just the integers?

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want to remove the space chars or keep only ints? What do you want to happen when you have an int in a string (e.g "3") ?

Comment: `df['Column 1] = [[x for x in i if isinstance(x, int)] for i in df['Column 1']]` ..?

Comment: @ds4940 just keep the ints

Comment: @ChrisA that wouldn't work since it doesn't look within each array in each row. That solution returned a column with an empty array in each row

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for something like so:

```
a = [1, 3, " "]
b = [i for i in a if i != " "]

print(b) #> [1, 3]
```

If you want to include other spaces to remove:

```
a = [1, 3, " ", ""]
b = [i for i in a if i not in (" ", "")]
```

If you want to only add `int` (if there are `str`, `float`, etc. this method will not generalize):

```py
a = [1, 3, " ", ""]
b = [i for i in a if isinstance(i, int)]
```

Comment: As my structure is a Dataframe series, this approach doesn't work. In theory your solution makes sense, but how would you change it for a Dataframe series? i.e. the series is a column where each row is an array

Comment: Does your dataframe just have a single column? You will need to use a method similar to he answer in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas to iterate (loop) over each of the elements (which themselves are a list) and modify them.

Comment: @vstone If you edit your answer with the code you used to initialize the `DataFrame` (reply here if you did), I could come back and edit these answers to help you out further -- otherwise, I'm honestly unsure how you have your `df` setup.